# Search tags/facets in Sitecore Item Buckets

Tags: sitecore

I'm looking to use the Sitecore Item Buckets package from Shared Source since I needed faceted search functionality and it makes sense to use the built in functionality rather than writing by own Lucene.Net search.

[Sitecore Item Buckets](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Item_Buckets.aspx)

I'm having trouble with the search, or maybe I am reading the documentation wrong.

According to the documentation in section 2.2.3 & 3.1.3 I just need to mark a field as "Is Facet" and my filter will show in the search results.

I've also defined a tag field on the template and changed the Tag Parent field in "/sitecore/system/Modules/Item Buckets/Item Buckets Settings" to point to correct folder. This is working correctly, I can apply a set of tags to an item and search from the Bucket UI using "tag:CSharp" and it brings back the correct results, but again there is no filter shown in the list. I've rebuilt the bucket indexes in all cases.

Am I missing something? Should these show up in the list automatically, do I need to change some settings or provide my own implementation?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dqr3.jpg)

This is all within the Buckets Client UI, I haven't started writing any code yet, and on a clean install of Sitecore 6.5 (update-5/rev. 120706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the documentation wording around this is entirely clear at the points I've mentioned. If you read further down the document though, section 4.3:

> Item Buckets ships with 5 different types of faceting.
>
> 1. Templates
> 2. Fields
> 3. Dates
> 4. Locations
> 5. Authors
>
> If you would like to introduce your own faceting categories then you only need to implement the IFacet interface.

There is an example of IFacet implementation in the documentation, or use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to look at the implementations of the existing Facets.

You also need to add an item to Sitecore: /sitecore/system/Modules/Item Buckets/Facets